# Spanish language Capitalization after Translation

Tags: traducción

We had the name of the grant program, Every Kid in a Park Transportation Grant, translated into Spanish. Are these words, once translated into Spanish, not capitalized?

Comment: No, in principle you would just capitalize the nouns that correspond to unique things. You can see [Uso de mayúsculas by Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp)

Comment: It's a matter of style and taste. To me those capitals don't look nice in English either. I personally would preferred all capitals or only the first word of the sentence.

Comment: I take back my previous comment. I read the link provided by @fedroqui and  I think you should keep the capitals on each word according to paragraph 4.23.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. They should be capitalized as defined by the RAE [here](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp)

> 4.23. Las palabras que forman parte de la denominación oficial de premios, distinciones, certámenes y grandes acontecimientos culturales o deportivos: el Premio Cervantes, los Goya, la Gran Cruz de la Orden de Alfonso X el Sabio, la Bienal de Venecia, la Feria del Libro, los Juegos Olímpicos. Por lo que respecta a los premios, cuando nos referimos al objeto material que los representa o a la persona que los ha recibido, se utiliza la minúscula: Esa actriz ya tiene dos goyas; Ha colocado el óscar encima del televisor; Esta noche entrevistan al nobel de literatura de este año.

Answer (score 0):

No, just capitalize names, cities, or places, and words after a dot.

For example:

> Hola, mi nombre es David. Nací en la ciudad de Bogotá.

translated to English:

> Hi, my name is David. I was born in Bogotá city.

Comment: Good answer but don't forget to read the [link](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp) suggested by @fedorqui.  I just did and learned that I was wrong on my previous comment. Check out the paragraph 4.23. I think a grant is kind of an award and should be capitalized.